# Sinch lib error: database is locked

Tags: android, parse-platform, sinch

Why is there a problem with sinch lib in Samsung Lollipop devices and not only Lollipop?

Service gives an error when starting up.

> 2238-2730/com.oombla E/sinch-android-rtc﹕ ERROR: sqlite Failed to exec 'PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL', error: database is locked (code: 5, extended code: 5)

Comment: @trust-ratch Right after login operation I start service this way:
... ParseUser.logInInBackground(...)...
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                    if (user != null) {
 ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
 if (currentUser != null) {
Logger.debug(getClass(), "chat: startChatService");
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MessageService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);  
}
This is is SignUp Activity. Then, I start service multiple times throughout the app, is this might be an issiue?

Comment: @trust-ratch I use ChatManager singleton class in which i

bindService using Activity reference that i passed. This is wrong as I see it.
I call:
ChatManager.getInstance().bindService(this);
But at some point in time activity reference is not proper.
Therefore this line inside ChatManager doesn't work:
activity.bindService(new Intent(activity, MessageService.class), serviceConnection, Activity.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
Doesn't work..

Right now I think this might be an issue...

Comment: Does break on the login or when you start the MessageService class?

Comment: @cjensen It was breaking on the MessageService start. The problem was singleton class, when I moved everything to the Activity it solved the issue.

Comment: @zkvarz can you help me regarding this issue. I am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide your code when you initialize since service

I'm using sinch with 2 samsung lollipop phones and it works fine